# EXCEL VBA -Getting #NAME?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to get user' id fro another excel file. On Main excel file there is only one column with username. I wrote below but it return #Name? instead of id.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer
Dim Client_id As Variant
Dim user_id As String
Dim Contract_id As Variant


Sub TestAdd()
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Next

For i = 2 To LastRow
user_id = "=VLOOKUP(Range(Cells(i, 3)),[RefUser.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)).Value = user_id
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid as a formula:

```
user_id = "=VLOOKUP(Range(Cells(i, 3)),[RefUser.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
```

Something like this would work:

```
user_id = "=VLOOKUP(C" & i & ",[RefUser.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
```

Then set that using `.Formula` and not `.Value`

You could set all these in one shot though.  Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

Sub TestAdd()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0,1)).Formula = _
             "=VLOOKUP(C2,[RefUser.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `VLookup` you need to provide some values to the function. The signature looks like [VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel).

- `lookup_value` is the value you are expecting to find.
- `table_array` is the range of cells that has the `lookup_value` in the leftmost column.
- `col_index_num` is the column number that contains the information you want to return when a match is found.
- `range_lookup` is the match that you're looking for. `0` can be used as a shorthand for False.

Assuming your `lookup_value` is in cell `C2` which corresponds to `Cells(i,3)` as i starts at 2, and your `table_array` is in `Range("M1:N10")`. You can use the formula `=VLOOKUP(C2,$M$1:$N$10,2,0)`. By omitting the `$` and leaving `C2` as a relative reference you can apply it to the range you want the values to be calculated. This is much more efficient then looping through and applying the the same formula to each cell individually.

```
Sub AddLookupFormula()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim formulaRange As Range
    Set formulaRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "B"), ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, "B"))

    Dim firstLookupCell As String
    firstLookupCell = formulaRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Address(False, False)

    Dim completedFormula As String
    completedFormula = "=VLOOKUP(" & firstLookupCell & ",$M$1:$N$10,2,0)"
    formulaRange.Formula = completedFormula
End Sub
```